# Importing React component from Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I would like to do the initial render for my React application on the server side, but am having trouble importing and using React components without using something like `babel/register` (which is [not suitable for production](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/user-handbook.md#toc-babel-register)).

I would rather not have to compile my server side code for production, but *would* like to load an node-suitable React component to send to the client via `res.send(React.createElement(Html))`.

When I run this I get...

> Unexpected token <

I assume this is because my components render method returns `<!doctype html>...</html`.

Is there a way I can have Node render a React component without having to use babel/compiling code before deploying?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can have Node render a React component without having
>   to use babel/compiling code before deploying?

No. Since JSX isn't real JavaScript, you need to transpile it at some point, either ahead of time (in a build script) or at run time (using `babel-register`).

Personally I ignore babel's advice to not use babel-register in production. It works just fine, I always cache + prime responses so performance isn't relevant. I'm open to hearing *why* transpiling with babel-register is bad though.

Comment: Do you have a repo with your implementation that I could look at? I'm working on a potentially large-scale app so I'm a little hesitant to use it in production, but would be interested in seeing how you've done so.

Comment: Sure, I'll probably make the repo private eventually but here it is: https://github.com/davidgilbertson/malla. I think you're quite right to be hesitant, I should take the time to find out why exactly they don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes.

this is from the official docs:

> ## ReactDOMServer
>
> The react-dom/server package allows you to render your
>   components on the server.
>
> ### ReactDOMServer.renderToString
>
> #### string renderToString(ReactElement element)
>
> Render a ReactElement to its initial HTML. This should only
>   be used on the server. React will return an HTML string. You can use
>   this method to generate HTML on the server and send the markup down on
>   the initial request for faster page loads and to allow search engines
>   to crawl your pages for SEO purposes.
>
> If you call ReactDOM.render() on a node that already has this
>   server-rendered markup, React will preserve it and only attach event
>   handlers, allowing you to have a very performant first-load
>   experience.
>
> ### ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup
>
> #### string  renderToStaticMarkup(ReactElement element)
>
> Similar to renderToString,
>   except this doesn't create extra DOM attributes such as data-react-id,
>   that React uses internally. This is useful if you want to use React as
>   a simple static page generator, as stripping away the extra attributes
>   can save lots of bytes.

However, if you want to use JSX you have to use babel, otherwise, you can use Reacts JS Syntax.

Here is a link to an example:

https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example

Comment: Is there documentation on how to compose non-JSX syntax? or a way use elements like `<!doctype...`?

Comment: I think, the example I posted the link to, shows all what you need to know.

Comment: It shows example rendering a `div`, `ul`, etc, but I would like to render `<!doctype html>` and many other elements. The example you posted does not cover such use cases.

Comment: @Himmel the problem is, there is no such component in React like a <!doctype html>, all the <div>, <ul> are actually React components, this is not HTML.. ;)